# How to scroll two JTextPane's?

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I am a Swing novice using NetBeans.  I want to vertically scroll two side-by-side JTextPane's.  The scrolling should be syncronized and done through a single scrollbar.

If I add JTextPanes from the NetBean designer they are automatically put inside a JScrollPane so they scroll independently.  I have deleted the enclosing scroll panes and put them in a JPanel instead so the JPanel can be the client of a single JScrollPane.  This seems to work except that when the JTextPanes are very long they seem to go beyong the end of the JPanel.  I can scroll the panel and both text panes to a certain point.  When I reach the bottom I can put a cusor in one of the text panes and arrow down beyond my field of view.

Here is code from my main method.  I have copied the layout from something that was generated by the NetBeans designer.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
topFrame aTopFrame = new topFrame();
JScrollPane scollBothDiffs = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
JPanel bothDiffsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
JTextPane leftDiffPane = diffPane1;
JTextPane rightDiffPane = diffPane2;


javax.swing.GroupLayout bothDiffsPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(bothDiffsPanel);
bothDiffsPanel.setLayout(bothDiffsPanelLayout);
bothDiffsPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
    bothDiffsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(bothDiffsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
        .addComponent(leftDiffPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 463, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
        .addComponent(rightDiffPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 463, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addContainerGap(52, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
bothDiffsPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
    bothDiffsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, bothDiffsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap()
        .addGroup(bothDiffsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addComponent(rightDiffPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 630, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(leftDiffPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 630, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addContainerGap())
);

scollBothDiffs.setViewportView(bothDiffsPanel);

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(aTopFrame.getContentPane());
aTopFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
        .addComponent(scollBothDiffs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 997, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addContainerGap())
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap()
        .addComponent(scollBothDiffs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 671, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addContainerGap())
);

aTopFrame.pack();
aTopFrame.setVisible(true);
}
});
```

Here is an image that shows my implementation of the first answer where the text panes are not limited to the horizontal display area.
[image: Image showing text panes that are too wide for the horizontal display area]

And this image shows the text panes limited in the horizontal display area but this example has the original issue of not scrolling vertically if the text panes are very long.
[image: Image showing text panes that are bounded horizontally]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A trick I've used before is to use two JScrollPanes, hide the vertical scroll bar for the left pane, and set its model to the model for the right scroll pane.  That way, when the user scrolls the right scroll bar, it updates both scroll panes, since they share the same model.  Here is an example that also has dual synchronized horizontal scroll bars at the bottom:

```
JTextPane leftDiffPane = diffPane1;
JTextPane rightDiffPane = diffPane2;
JScrollPane spLeft = new JScrollPane(leftDiffPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
JScrollPane spRight = new JScrollPane(leftDiffPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
spLeft.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(spRight.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());
spLeft.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(spRight.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());

// ...
```

Note that it might not work so well if your JTextPanes have different sizes (I haven't tried it, but my best guess is it would cause problems)

You can also fix mouse wheel scrolling by redirecting wheel events from the left scroll pane to the right one:

```
spLeft.setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);
spLeft.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        spRight.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: This almost works but the left pane is wider than the right because the right has some width eaten up by the scrollbar.  This means that the two panes do not wrap the same so the text gets out of sync as you go down the pane.

Comment: @mikeatv: read the Swing tutorial on using layout managers properly, make sure both JScrollPanes display the same scroll bars too.

Comment: +1, There is no need to hide the scrollbar, just share the model and you can use either scrollbar to scroll both text panes. and yes this technique is only for text panes of the same size.

Comment: This got me what I needed but I would have prefred not using two scrollbars.

Comment: @mikeatv - are you referring to the two horizontal scroll bars?  You might be able to hide both of them and use a JScrollBar below the panel.  The hard part would be properly tying the scroll models for the scroll panes to the scroll bar, I believe the bounded ranges must be the same.

Comment: "no need to hide the scrollbar(s)" -- for me, it worked for images of the same size

Answer (score 4):

If you use a [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) for both of your `JTextPane` and then wrap it with `JScrollPane`, the Scroll Bar will be for both JTextPanes since the `GridLayout` gets divided into equal sized rectangles.

Something like this should work (Tested on Java 6)

```
// Text Panes initialization. I am just setting text so you can see
// what each pane is.
JTextPane leftDiffPane = new JTextPane();
leftDiffPane.setText("left");
JTextPane rightDiffPane = new JTextPane();
rightDiffPane.setText("right");

// Wrap the Text Panes with a Panel since you can only
// have a single component within a scroll pane.      
JPanel bothDiffsPanel = new JPanel();
bothDiffsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
bothDiffsPanel.add(leftDiffPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
bothDiffsPanel.add(rightDiffPane, BorderLayout.EAST);

// Fill in the frame with both of the panels.
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(new JScrollPane(bothDiffsPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you use the above approach, if amending text to either `JTextPanes` overflow the dimensions, the scroll bar will appear and when used, it will scroll both of the components. If amending text overflows a component, it will scroll down so your input will be visible.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This looks promising.  Thank you.  But now the text panes are not limited by the horizontal display area.  They don't wrap and scroll off way to the side.  The wrapping was what made the text panes so long in the first case.  The panes need to be visible at the same time for comparison.

Comment: No problem, What do you mean by limited by the horizontal display area? The panes above are visible at the same time for comparison. If you add 20 lines in the left and 20 lines on the right, but the viewing area is just 10 lines, if you scroll the left pane, the right pane will be scrolled. Did you want different behaviours?

Comment: I have added images to the question to show what I mean about the text panes not being limited by the horizontal display area.  I would like them to split the horizontal display area of the enclosing frame.

Comment: In the second image the width of the text panes are bounded by a maximum.  This is OK.  I don't need to have the panes split the available width if the enclosing frame is resized narrower than some reasonable value.  However, the text panes will hold some very long lines so the they have to be bounded.  Either by the enclosing frame or by some reasonable value.